# Imports and ill-behaved SBT plugins

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to define parsers in a `build.sbt` file.

I'm using this plugin, by adding this line in `plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.gilt" % "sbt-dependency-graph-sugar" % "0.7.4")
```

When specifiying this in `build.sbt`:

```
import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._

val servers = token(
    literal("desarrollo") | 
    literal("parametrizacion")
)
```

`SBT` complains with this error message:

```
reference to literal is ambiguous;
reference to token is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._
and import _root_.gilt.DependencyGraph._
```

How can I avoid this namespace clashing of basic SBT classes?.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is this:

```
import sbt.complete.{DefaultParsers ⇒ DP}
import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._

val servers = DP.token(
    DP.literal("desarrollo") | 
    DP.literal("parametrizacion")
)
```

I don't fully like it, because it adds clutter.
The ideal solution is to hide unwanted imports.

Answer (score 0):

This solution creates a new scope, so there's no interference with imports:

```
name := "MyProject"

{
    import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._

    val servers = token(
        "desarrollo" | "parametrizacion"
    )
}
```